# Exception in thread "main" Method call Java

Tags: java

I am very new into Java and I'm sorry if my question is too simple but since I can't find the reason why the switch statement is never executed, I'm still blocked.
Here's the code:

```
static void findSpot(String[][] parking) {
    boolean control = false, repeat;


    System.out.println("Insert o Floor : Spot");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] floorSpot = s.nextLine().split(":");

    int floor, spot;
    floor = Integer.parseInt(floorSpot[0]);
    spot = Integer.parseInt(floorSpot[1]);

    if (floor >= parking.length) {
        System.out.println("Invalid floor number!");
    }


    System.out.println("Insert registry: 00-00-AA  00-AA-00");
    String registry = s.nextLine();
    repeat = validateRegistry(registry);

    if (!repeat) {
        System.out.println("Invalide format.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also show the (full) stack trace.

Comment: there is no switch statement in you code ....

Comment: @Stultuske I'm glad I'm not going mad, I was going to ask the same thing...

Comment: @MichaelBerry it does, however, explain why it isn't executed :)

Comment: it seems you remove some part of your program, which make it unreadable

Comment: @Stultuske Absolutely. I sure wish my code was that easy to debug ;-)

Comment: Seems like he gave wrong code

Comment: @paul your code is still incomplete. it doesn't show in which method it is, so how are we to know how, or with which parameters it is called?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but the definitions on the Stack over flow, won't allow me to publish the entire code on here, and shortly explain the errors:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static java.lang.System.out;



public class ex17 {

    public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       int x=args.length;// 
       String[][] parking=new String[x][];

        setPositions(parking,args);

        boolean exit = false;
  while (!exit) {
            char choice;

            out.println("\nE- Entrance vehicle");
            out.println("T- Terminate");
            out.print("Option ->  ");
           choice = in.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

            switch (choice) {
                case 'e':
                    findSpot(parking);
                    break;
                    case 't':
                    exit=quitProgram();
                    break;
                default:
                    out.println(Invalid\n".toUpperCase());
                    break;


            }
static void findSpot(String[][] parking) {
    boolean control = false, repeat;


    System.out.println("Insert o Floor : Spot");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] floorSpot = s.nextLine().split(":");

    int floor, spot;
    floor = Integer.parseInt(floorSpot[0]);
    spot = Integer.parseInt(floorSpot[1]);

    if (floor >= parking.length) {
        System.out.println("Invalid floor number!");
    }


    System.out.println("Insert registry: 00-00-AA  00-AA-00");
    String registry = s.nextLine();
    repeat = validateRegistry(registry);

    if (!repeat) {
        System.out.println("Invalide format.");
    }
}
```